# How can I search better for topics already covered?

Tags: feature-request, search

Twice now I've started to ask a question only to be told parts were already covered.

Would be so much easier to have a Search Box up top, to be able to search knowledge base before trying to formulate a good enough question, or maybe a more obvious way in which to search tags.

I see that here was a similar question to this, back in Nov 13 2017 by @JBH, but not the same. So, while I would like to read that discussion at my ease, that's not going to happen because as soon as I post this question, I will lose that link.

Comment: Go to www.google.com. In the box, enter your search terms followed by `site:worldbuilding.stackexchange.com`. Magic. (And ys, there *is* a search box at the top of the page. It works differently than Google, it has some refinements which Google doesn't, but overall using a real search engine is much more likely to provide useful results.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### There are two tools to avoid duplicates

#### The search bar

At the very top, you can search for questions using keywords. L.Dutch showed for your computer's web browser. In case you are on a mobile phone, there's a magnifying glass on the menu at the top.

When using search engines, a good practice is to search incrementally by typing keywords. This lower the chances of skipping unwillingly a question, and narrows dynamically the results. For instance, don't ask "[How big my Giant can be under Earth's gravity?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=How%20big%20my%20Giant%20can%20be%20under%20Earth%27s%20gravity%3F)", but first "[Giant size](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=Giant%20size)", then extend or replace keywords if searches aren't satisfactory or give too many results. E.g. : add "[human](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=Giant%20size%20human)" if you want to read more about humans than planets -a.k.a. gas giants-, or use "height" or "big" instead of "size".

Also, you can use [tags] to narrow your search. For instance "[[fantasy-races] Giant Size](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfantasy-races%5D%20Giant%20size)". It should be used when the search engine confuses topics in different themes too much. There are more tools to narrow your search [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/searching).

#### The similar questions snippet when writing your own questions

This tool is quite reliable and appears right when you are writing your question!

[image: Example screenshot with giants]
<sup>An example with the same giant question.</sup>

Make a quick draft of your question and this tool will tell you the similar questions it found. Note that the title alone is sometimes insufficient, it works better when you start writing the body too :).

Comment: Thank you for these details, the How to search page will save me a lot of frustration.

Answer (score 4):

> Would be so much easier to have a Search Box up top

Don't you have it already?

[image]

Type the strings you want to search on, and you will get a list of content matching those strings.

Comment: My apologies. I just did not see the search box up there.